# Query a filter value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets where Sheet 1 (`Data Q1`) contains all the values for a subject, lesson, names, and percentages of each student's total for a subject. On the next sheet (`NYC/C`) I want to filter a value.

For Instance: If Data Q 1 contains `Lesedi Selebalo` `Lesson 1` 'Subject Title' insert  'Percentage' contained.

```
=filter("NamedRange1="Lesson1", Namedrange2="subject name", namedrange3="student name and surname) =Query(Namedrange Percentage)
```

I have included [this document with the example of `PAS Learning Method and Moodle`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C676nvi745hkvCjsAkxm95yatxX8qkR7GeQOJbnWsaU/edit?usp=sharing).

A sample of data input (Sheet `Data Q1`):

[image: Sample of data input (Sheet <code>Data Q1</code>)]

Selection from `NYC/C`:

[image: Selection from <code>NYC/C</code>]

Answer (score 0):

one-cell solution:

```
={QUERY('Data Q1'!A1:F, "select D 
                         where A like 'Quarter 1' 
                           and B like 'Lesson 1' 
                           and C like 'PAS: Learning Method and Moodle' 
                           and F like '"&A6&"'"),
  QUERY('Data Q1'!A1:F, "select D 
                         where A like 'Quarter 1' 
                           and B like 'Lesson 2' 
                           and C like 'PAS: Learning Method and Moodle' 
                           and F like '"&A6&"'")}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please try in AG6:

```
=query('Data Q1'!A1:F14000,"select D where A like 'Quarter 1' and B like 'Lesson 1' and C like 'PAS: Learning Method and Moodle' and F like '"&A6&"'")
```

and for AH6 change `Lesson 1` to `Lesson 2`.

With a slight adjustment to your layout (the headings) instead of the above formulae a single, much shorter, formula (copied across) might suit.

Comment: Yes that done it. You are a legend. Thank you so much for the help and effort i really appreciate it